# Changing Application Toolbar item icons dynamically via ABAP

Tags: abap, dynpro

I am searching for a way to edit items of the Application Toolbar of an SAP Dynpro dynamically via ABAP at runtime. More precisely, I would like to change the icon of such an item.
Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a global field in your program `TEXT_1 TYPE SMP_DYNTXT`. Define your function code text type in your GUI status as dynamic and enter your previously defined field.

At runtime assign your icon and text:

```
TEXT_1-ICON_ID    = '@DL@'.
TEXT_1-ICON_TEXT  = 'MY_TEXT'.
```

This is documented [here.](https://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_04/helpdata/EN/d1/801e3a454211d189710000e8322d00/frameset.htm)

Comment: btw. can I also disable icons (grey out) via this mechanism?

Comment: For documentation. This helped me figuring out on how to disable/grey out elements of the status bar: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/84401